# Complexity of recursive permutation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, time-complexity

I'm reading Richard Bird's Algorithm design with Haskell, in section 2.2, he considers the following algorithm to calculate the list of permutations of a list:

```
perms = foldr (concatMap · inserts) [[]]
inserts x [] = [[x]]
inserts x (y : ys)=(x : y : ys):map (y:) (inserts x ys)
```

Then he concludes the recurrence relation for T (perms running time) to be

```
T(n+1) = T(n) +n!(I(n) +Θ(n^2))
```

With the justification

> The function I(n) is the time to compute the list of insertions of a new element in
> a permutation of length n. There are n+1 results, each of which is a list of length
> n+1, and it takes Θ(n^2) to concatenate them. Finally, there are n! permutations of
> a list of length n, so the insertions are computed n! times.

My question is why does the term `Θ(n^2)` appear?
I tried to follow the book method, and expanded the definition using explicit recursion

```
perms []=[[]]
perms (x:xs)=concatMap.inserts x foldr (concatMap.inserts) [[]] xs
```

So, we have `T(n)` (the time required to find the permutations of the tail represented by the foldr term in the recursion), now using `I(n)` with the above definition, it is the cost of mapping the `inserts x` over a single element of `foldr (concatMap.inserts) [[]] xs`, which produces a list of `n+1` lists (the there are n+1 possible indices for insertion) each list contains `n+1` elements (a permutation of length `n` with one more element), what I don't understand is the need to concatenate those `n+1` lists, since the concatenation operation is done on the result of map as a whole, not mapped over every `inserts x` output, that is we have

`concat.map (inserts x) [L_1,L_2,...,L_(n!)],`
where each `L_i` has `length n` and represents a permutation of n elements.

`=concat [ inserts x L_1,inserts L_2,....]`

`=concat [ LL_1,LL_2,...,LL_(n!)]`
where each `LL_i` is a list of `n+1`lists `[P_(i,1),P_(i,2)...,P(i,n+1)]` with each `P_(i,j)` having `n+1` elements.

So the concatenation is is applied to the list

`[ LL_1,LL_2,...,LL_(n!)]=[P_(1,1),P_(1,2)...,P(1,n+1),P_(2,1),P_(2,2)...,P_(n!,n+1)]`

The book previously computes the complexity of the `concat xss` to be `Θ(mn)` with `m=length xss` consisting of lists each with `length n`, my analysis gives the recurrence relation

`T(n+1)=T(n) + n!*I(n) + Θ(n!*(n+1))`, Is this correct?

**Edit**

To be more clear, from the recursive definition,

1. `T(n)` is the cost to calculate the permutations of length n.
2. `I(n)` is the cost to perform a single `inserts x` operation, multiplied by the number of times it will be done, which gives `n!*I(n)`
3. `Θ(n!*(n+1))` is the complexity of the `concat`.

Comment: I think Bird has just been imprecise here. It costs O(n^2) to *create* the lists, and then the actual `concat` is comparatively cheap. So analyze the time it takes to build all the `P(i,j)`s in the first place, not the time it takes to concatenate all the `LL_i`s.

Comment: I think you are taking about solving `I(n)`  explicitly, he does it, with the same justification you gave, here it is " . Now
`I(n+1) = I(n) +Θ(n)`
There are n+1 ways to add a new element to a list of length n, so it takes `Θ(n)` steps to perform the map operations. That gives `I(n) = Θ(n^2)`."

Comment: Also the concat operation is not at all cheap, since it's an function in the length of the result list, now every list returned by `inserts x` has `n+1` lists, and there are `n!` maps, which gives `Θ((n+1)!)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like Bird has made a mistake and you are correct.  Yes, each of the n! insertions creates a list of n+1 results, each of which is a list of n+1 elements, but Bird's description appears to make it clear that he is imagining, for each result, the concatenation of the n+1 lists of n+1 elements into a single list of elements requiring O(n^2) time for each of the n! results, when it is only the outer list of n! lists of n+1 lists that must be concatenated into a length n!*(n+1)=(n+1)! list of *lists* of elements.

Concretely, in computing permutations of `[1,2,3]`, it takes T(2) to compute:

```
[[2,3],[3,2]]
```

and it takes I(3) *each* for the 2! insertion results:

```
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
[[1,3,2],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

However, concatenating these does not require an O(3^2) operation for each insertion result; it only requires concatenating the 2! insertion results themselves, each of length 3, previously established as an O(2!*3) or simply O(3!) operation.

So, you're right that it should read:

```
T(n+1) = T(n) + n!I(n) + O((n+1)!)
```

This doesn't appear in the [list of errata](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/publications/books/adwh/errata.html) so maybe you should send an email to the address listed on that page and see if he agrees.

Comment: Thanks, you forgot to add `T(n)` in the last equation.